# How to know which project a source file belongs to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP. I am working on a "solution" of 27 projects. Each project contains several source files - *.cpp files and header files *.h.

Now, using the find function (control + f) I have managed to open a source file A.cpp. However, I do not know which project it belongs to. I have searched the Internet without success. I am sure there must be a way, sorry for being a noob.

In Eclipse there is a way of doing this, is there a way to do this in VS as well?

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+F, Look in "Entire Solution",look at these filetypes: "*.vcxproj". Maybe there is a cleaner solution, but this works for me.

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > tick the "Track active item in Solution Explorer" option.

Comment: @HansPassant your solution was exactly what I was looking for, answer down below so I can select it as my answer.

Comment: Just write your own post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: What if one source file belongs to multiple projects?

Comment: @knivil when using ctrl+f then it opens the first occurence i.e. whichever Project it searches first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+; and start typing the name of the file.  That will limit the solution explorer view to just the named file.  You can open the file from there, too.  That's typically easier than using File/Open, provided that the file is in your solution.

[image]

Still a few more keystrokes once you've opened a file using a text search , but I think it is the simplest way.

Comment: You are right in a big project my method gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer courtesy HansPassant.

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > tick the "Track active item in Solution Explorer" option. This will highlight the source file in the project in the solution explorer window. Just as it does in eclipse.

Comment: In practice, I find this doesn't work so well with large projects.  This option causes things to jump around too much. It also (at least in VS 2015) doesn't expand your folders, so it doesn't work most of the time.